# How to Build a Parent's Children Only Once in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child

How can I ensure that a Parent only builds its Children n times in Rails?

Is there a way to find non-persisted instances?

I'm currently having a problem where I create the children on the first load of a page.  When a user refreshes the page, the children are not loaded because they have already been created, but have not been persisted.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

In the view:

```
if ( session[:members_built] == false )
    @membership.build_members
    session[:members_built] = true
end

...

  <% f.fields_for :members do |ff| %>
<%= render :partial => "member", :locals => { :ff => ff } %>
```

In the model:

```
  def build_members
    (membership_type.adults - 1).times {members.build}
  end
```

Comment: code added, if I've missed anything else relevant please let me know

Comment: Please show us your controller.

Comment: controller just retrieves the membership using an id, nothing else

Comment: If you build 5 members in #new then the form should display 5 members. When the user submits that form to #create and #create finds an error, it will render the form again and there should only be 5 members. It will only create more members if you call #build_members in #create or in the form.

Comment: Hi Monocle, thanks.  Problem is that the number of members is dynamic and depends on the user input in the form.  How can I build the children when the parent hasn't been made yet?

Comment: You could make a multi step form (see Railscasts) or send an Ajax request when the user inputs the required parent information and have Rails send you back the appropriate form elements. Or you could create all the form elements via javascript.

Comment: Thanks again, but I don't want to rely on JavaScript for this functionality (high % of visitors have it disabled).  There must be another solution?

Comment: Try the multistep form then. http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: I believe that the same problem would still exist.  Need a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( session[:members_built] == false )
  @membership.build_members
  session[:members_built] = true
end
```

I would recommend not having code like this is your views. It's going against MVC principles. So move it into the controller. Also checkout the [Rails Guides for associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).

So you could do something like

```
@membership.build_members
```

in your controller. You don't have to use a session variable to remember if you called #build_members because using #build doesn't save the object. So when a user refreshes the page, the controller will call #build_members again and your view should be what you want.

Comment: The problem with this is that it can result in duplicate members, if for example, the form is submitted with errors and is reloaded...!

Comment: If they're unpersisted, they don't exist beyond the existing request cycle, and consequently aren't duplicated...

Comment: The reason I used the session is to stop the children being built too many times.  I did experience this happening, because when the form submits with an error it stores the form values in the session.  The result is duplicates.  Any ideas on getting round this problem? Would skipping @membership.build_members if !params[:membership].empty? do the trick?